# Passing an object as a parameter, to pass an object's variable instead

Tags: c++, oop, class

Language: CPP (C++)

I'm not sure if Dreamed this up, but is it possible to pass a class object as a parameter to a function that expects NOT the class type, but a type that is IN the class.

It would be really nice to, instead of doing function(object->target_variable)
that I could have some rule, so i could then just do

```
function(object)
```

which would equal:

```
function(object->target_variable)
```

Is there some way to specify this desired behaviour?

Comment: The behaviour I'm looking for is kind of like in Java when you pass an Object to a Print function. I like how that happens automatically and keeps the code looking clean.

Comment: Why, for heaven's sake, would you want to do that? Is that some kind of novel make-code-looking-more-obscure-that-it-is idiom?

Comment: @PaulMichalik I am writing an Engine and my desire is to make the API as simple as possible. Working in this way makes the code look cleaner, the end user does not have to have as much knowledge of the classes underlying part's. everything is automatic,

Comment: @bazz Aha, but this in no way what happens there. The `Print` function uses some kind of contract, to get the textual representation of the object. You could do the same in C++ by defining such a contract e.g. by requiring an implementation of `virtual std::string IPrintable::ToString() const`

Comment: Well, let's get into detail. I'm not trying to redefine a string contract. Rather it's with something called an SDL_Surface, which luckily the standard libraries PROBABLY don't interfere with. But since there is no pre-existing relationship / contract, I'm still not sure how to make one

Comment: @bazz Hm, I commented on the Java parallel, the other one I don't really understand. Could you add an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just figured out an easy alternative Way that still fits in nicely with the Engine workings. It involves nothing fancy, just another class function. It would have been nice to know if what I wanted to do can be done though, so I am still open to any future posts. For those interested, I apologize for my vagueness but the project is deep and I work on it day and night..

Comment: @PaulMichalik in hindsight, it's like the Java parallel except I would like to apply it to independent types and independent functions. Unlike the standard string type and standard printing functions.

Comment: @PaulMichalik So basically a contract like you said, only it would be myfunction(SDL_Surface *surface) that would know to take myfunction(classobject) and that it knows to use classobject's surface variable aka classobject->surface or classobject.surface 

just like in Java, where you pass the object to the print and there is some contract that the print function knows to use the Objects tostring method..

Comment: Why isn't it enough to overload?: `void myfunction(Thing* classobject) { myfunction(classobject->surface); }`

Comment: @molbdnilo the function deals works with type X. many different classes have type X, but this function should not only work with one of those classes, it should work with type X. How, and would it be clean, to overload in that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cast operator in the class, then every time some function expects a certain type and you provide an instance of the class it will provide its member. Doesn't work if you have multiple members you might want to be handled like this (with the same type).

Or you can overload the function, accepting a reference to an instance of the class and calling the original function with the instances member instead. The drawback here is that you need to overload the function for every class, or create a common ancestor for all these classes (an interface or "contract").

Comment: I really like this answer.. Considering the drawback.... im going to post another answer demonstrating what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

OK, that does not fit into a comment any more. If it is "basically a contract" so create one! For example:

```
struct IDeliverSDLSurface {
    virtual SDL_Surface* GetSurface() const = 0;
    virtual ~IDeliverSDLSurface() = default;
};

class A : public IDeliverSDLSurface {
    SDL_Surface* m_Surface;

    // implements IDeliverSDLSurface
    virtual SDL_Surface* GetSurface() const
    {
        return m_Surface;
    }

    // other stuff    
};

class B : public IDeliverSDLSurface { /* etc */ };

// etc.
```

Then write a intermediate layer, where the services take `IDeliverSDLSurface*` and pass the surface to the proper "engine" service, e.g.:

```
namespace Intermediate {
    void Foo(IDeliverSDLSurface* p_Object)
    {
        // call engine's Foo
        Engine::Foo(p_Object->GetSurface());
    }

    void Bar(IDeliverSDLSurface* p_Object)
    {
        // call engine's Bar
        Engine::Bar(p_Object->GetSurface());
    }

    // etc
}
```

One could write a more sophisticated (semi-automatic) dispatcher of that kind, but you get the idea... On the client side you can call functions in `Intermediate` with all instances of all types which implement `IDeliverSDLSurface`:

```
A tA;
Intermediate::Foo(&tA);

B tB;
Intermediate::Bar(&tB);

// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

as SvenS pointed out, you can create a cast operator in the class. Here is an example to cast to a const char*. this code goes in your class:

```
// operator to cast to a const char *
// 
operator const char *()
{
    m_pStr[m_nSize] = '\0';
    return(m_pStr);
}
```

for full example see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y.aspx